# paypal merchant account not working

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I was testing locally on Xampp with a Sandbox Merchant account and it worked perfectly.  When I modified the site on my client's staging server to use those credentials, I began to get a message locally:
"There is a problem with the merchant account."

The site on my client's staging server still worked with those sandbox credentials.

Thankfully, I had another merchant account to use locally and it is working again but this causes me to wonder if it is possible to use a merchant account on only one site at a time.

I have several WooCommerce development project afoots and it would be sad if that is true, mostly because it is a nuisance.

Comment: what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, and appears to be for PayPal Support instead.